# CSS get classes

Tags: css

I have to get some label in css, but there is few classes that i need to pass to get to one i want. I have 2 pages but i need to change only one, and i think it's possible because there is few differences in classes.
This is HTML code of both.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group has-input-icon  ">
   <label for="">Check in</label> <!--This label i need to catch-->
```

Second

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group has-input-icon search-destination">
   <label for="">Destination</label>
```

In have to get label from first code, so how do i get this class with css?
something like .col-sm-4->form-group->has-input-icon->label, i need to catch all of that classes to be more specific what i need to change, how to write it?

Comment: Something like that? `div .form-group.has-input-icon label {}`

Comment: Already tried, nothing happened.

Comment: `.form-group .has-input-icon` for the first element and specific to the second you can use `.search-destination` given, that search Destination is unique. If not, any Element with the class will be styled. If you want to just style this particular element you could use an id if neccessary. This is just a comment, since I'm not entirely sure if this is the best practice, but it works. Look up CSS at MDN to get a nice look at it and how to use CSS. Greets

Comment: Tried with this too .col-sm-4.form-group.has-input-icon label{} still nothing

Answer (score 1):

To target the first element:

```
.col-sm-4 .form-group label {
    background:red
}
```

To target the second element:

```
.col-sm-4 .form-group.search-destination label {
    background:orange
}
```

To target the first, but exclude the second, and or others:

```
.col-sm-4 .form-group:not(.search-destination) label {
    background:orange
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.col-sm-4 > .form-group.has-input-icon > label {
  color: red;
}

.col-sm-6 > .form-group.has-input-icon.search-destination > label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group has-input-icon  ">
  <label for="">Check in</label> <!--This label i need to catch-->
 </div>
</div>
   
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-group has-input-icon search-destination">
  <label for="">Destination</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

- `>` means "first level children"
- Mulitple selectors without space or
  other separators means that all those selectors must apply on same
  element.   Example: `.form-group.has-input-icon.search-destination`
  means that all of these 3 classes must be on the selected element.

Comment: Very simple. I like it!

Comment: this requires targeting both elements, where the question stated 1 element to be targeted, which can be done with the css :not(), see my answer below @awe

Comment: @DGRFDSGN The `.col-sm-4` at top level is enough to filter the first, since the second has `.col-sm-6` at top level. I guess you didn't see that they were different. Your version with using  `:not(.search-destination)` will also work if not including any `.col-sm-` selectors at top level.